# How to stop ZSH from merging history for all closing tabs?

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I use combination of `zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` and **iTerm2** for development on Mac.
I'm frustrated with the following issue:

- **N** tabs opened
- close the terminal
- reopen it (with *Use system Window Restoration Setting*)
- the history from all previously opened tabs got merged into one for every reopened tab

The question: How to preserve separated history for every reopened tab?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Per https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2537,

Add `unsetopt share_history` to your .zshrc file.

Comment: It seems like disabling shared history for running tabs. But is still got merged after restore.

Comment: any idea what the .bash_profile equivalent of this should be?

Comment: This pleases Zulthar.

Answer (score 4):

Unless iTerm2 actually just hides a tab on closing and keeps the shell session running in the background (which, according to [the iTerm2 website](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences.html), seems to be an option), it is not possible to completely restore a shell session. In your case it seems like a new shell session is created when restoring a tab, which leads to the history being read from `$HISTFILE`.

If you want to prevent any merging of history, you have to ensure that of the options `APPEND_HISTORY`, `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY` only the first one is set:

```
setopt noincappendhistory
setopt nosharehistory
setopt appendhistory
```

This will lead to new entries in the history (i.e. commands run during the session) only being appended to the history file when the shell exits. So when you close a session, the next shell (re-)opened will have lines of the just previously closed shell on the bottom of the history.

---

Another option could be to have separate history files for each shell session and device your own method of loading a history from these files using the `fc` builtin. This would at least in part depend on whether it is possible to differentiate between iTerm2 tabs from within a shell session (for example via some environment variable) and whether this holds true when re-opening a tab.

Comment: So, looks like there's no easy way?

Comment: i have set up like this but doesnt work:
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
setopt noincappendhistory
unsetopt nosharehistory
unsetopt appendhistory

Comment: @Arie This is equivalent to `setopt sharehistory noincappendhistory noappendhistory`, which would be a valid setting. Aside form that `HISTFILE` needs to be set to a filename in an existing directory and `SAVEHIST` and `HISTSIZE` need to be set to positive integer values. If either `HISTFILE` or `SAVEHIST` are unset, no file will be written or read. If `HISTSIZE` is unset or 0, the history will be written, but will not availabe in the shell.

Comment: @Adaephon i dont get so what should be written in zshrc to make it work?

Comment: @Arie: I don't think you can make it work without either (1) changes to how iTerm "saves" sessions, or (2) having a different history file for each shell session.